# Copying a bitmap from a native call

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java method that is being called from native c code. It's job is simple, copy a bitmap. But it makes it bomb out without error.

```
public synchronized Bitmap copyScreen() {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "before copy Screen");
                          //Any of these lines make it bomb out.
        // Bitmap copy = bmp.copy(bmp.getConfig(), false);
        //Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(),
        //      bmp.getConfig());
        Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(800, 480, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Log.d(TAG, "after copy Screen");
        return copy;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "copyScreen", ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can call this `copyScreen` from Java without problem. Only when it's called from JNI that it bombs.

If I don't do either copy line, it also works fine.

The log cat just shows:

> 11-15 20:10:49.234: D/GraphicsBuffer(24341): before copy Screen

Note, the native code is running in a thread seperate to the main. I have synced all access to the `bmp` field. But even making a new bitmap without causes it to quit. If the bitmap is small, it's OK.

```
Bitmap copy = Bitmap.createBitmap(80, 48, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Works, so is there some limit to what I can allocate from JNI?

Comment: What is the logcat bomb output?

Comment: Bitmap would be still allocated in Java heap. What do you mean by bomb? Nothing happens, app crashes, there must be some segfault or something at least... Try to make a isolated app to reproduce the error and publish JNI code as well.

Comment: @auselen That's what I'd have thought. Log cat shows zilch, just my log messages and general system stuff. I will try and make small reproduction app.

Comment: @auselen Yeah, it is wierd, no seg fault or anything. I think I have cracked it though while working on another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure my problem was the way I kept a ref to the java environment:

**My old main and getJNIEnv**

```
 JNIEnv *_env;

 JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_comp_prod_main(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass thiz) {
    LOGV("Main called %d", __LINE__);
    _env = (JNIEnv *) ((*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, env));
      main(); //somewhere in here it calls back to the java which creates the bitmap
    _env = NULL;
  }

  JNIEnv *getJNIEnv(void) {
     return _env;
  }
```

**My new main and getJNIEnv**

```
JavaVM *jvm;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_comp_prod_main(JNIEnv *env,
        jclass thiz) {
    LOGV("Main called %d", __LINE__);
    //this is how to cache it for other threads
    jint rs = (*env)->GetJavaVM(env, &jvm);
    assert (rs == JNI_OK);
    main(); //somewhere in here it calls back to the java which creates the bitmap
    jvm = NULL;
}

JNIEnv *getJNIEnv(void) {
    JNIEnv *env;
     jint rs = (*jvm)->AttachCurrentThread(jvm, &env, NULL);
     assert (rs == JNI_OK);
     if(env == NULL)
     {
       LOGV("env is NULL");
     }
     return env;
}
```

FYI all the c is single threaded, but runs in seperate thread to main. This is how it is started from Java:

```
Runnable runTerm = new Runnable() {

public void run() {
  // call main()
  Log.i(TAG, "About to call main on the c!");
  try {
    Terminal.main();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
};

t = new Thread(runTerm, "C thread");
t.start();
```